# Validating Webhook for configmap

Tags: kubernetes

I have `Validating Webhook` that triggers when some `CRDs resources` get `[CREATE, UPDATE]` operations.
I wanted to add for that, a specific configmap that will trigger that validating webhook.

Under the same namespace, I have multiple CRDs and configmaps, but I wanted to trigger the webhook also for one of the configmaps.

[This](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/generated/kubernetes-api/v1.19/#validatingwebhook-v1beta1-admissionregistration-k8s-io) is the `ValidatingWebhook v1beta1 admissionregistration.k8s.io` properties.

I guess the `namespaceSelector` is not the perfect match for my needs since it triggers for any configmap under that namespace. Tried to understand also if the `objectSelector` is good solution, but couldnt fully understand.

This is the relevent part of my webhook configurations:

```
webhooks:
- name: myWebhook.webhook
  clientConfig:
  ***
  failurePolicy:
  ***
  rules:
   - operations: ['CREATE', 'UPDATE']
     apiGroups: ***
     apiVersion: ***
     resources: [CRD_resource_1, CRD_resource_2]
```

So I guess that my question is- how can I pick one of the multiple configmaps to triger my validation webhook?

Many thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You definitely should use `objectSelector` in order to act only on specific configMaps.
You can make sure you put some specific label on those configMaps and configure your webhook:

```
  objectSelector:
    matchLabels:
      myCoolConfigMaps: true
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. do I have to label the rest of the CRDs (CRD_resource_1, CRD_resource_2) with the same label of configmap as well?

Comment: You can make separate webhook configuration for the CRD and the ConfigMaps.
It means adding another section under the webhooks array.